# No Query String vs Ignore Query String in WordPress

Tags: cache, cloudflare

I use Cloudflare and there is an option of choosing Cache level. The following are the level of Caches available [check image]-

[image]

I have selected **Standard**. Which one should I be using for better page loading? I am not a developer, so don't expect me to understand coding language.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you don't understand what is meant by the query string and you're not a developer, then `Standard` will be fine. It's the safest option without knowing more about your setup—choosing `Ignore Query String` could break your WordPress site depending on how it's set up.